# Get Object by Order in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list `componentlist` containing codes and I have an object `productDetailsResponse` containing components

```
List<ComponentCode> listComponents;

public class ComponentCode {   
    public string code{get;set;}
}
```

Now I want to assign each productDetailsResponse.components's `productType` in a string but in the same order as present in `componentlist`

```
public class ProductDetailsResponse{
public Component[] components{get;set;}
}
public class Component {
public string componentCode{get;set;}
public ProductType productType{get;set;}
}

string productTypes = string.Empty;
productTypes += //LINQ
```

For example if `listComponents` contains

```
["B"]
["A"]
```

And `productDetailsResponse.components` contains

```
["A","Phone"]
["B","TV"]
```

my string `productTypes` should contain `TVPhone`. So basically I want to extract info in the same order as of `listComponents`

Is it possible to achieve this using LINQ?

Comment: It is possible - join/where, order by and select - but please show what you have tried

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Select` on your `listComponents` to retrieve information from `productDetailsResponse`.

So something like

```
listComponents.Select( component => productDetailsResponse.components
   .First( x => x.componentCode==component).productType 
)
```

And finally you can use `string.Join` to concat the result into one big string